# Zombie comedy movie about dumb college students

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

This zombie comedy movie I watched had a bunch of high school or maybe college students as the protagonists.

They go to a shop that sells occult items. One of them accidentally knocks over an urn or some other fragile object, which causes it to shatter. The shopkeeper warns them that they have just unleashed an evil force, and that anything they say in the shop will come true. The students then jokingly wish that, whenever they make eye contact with someone after midnight, that person will commit suicide and then reanimate as a zombie. Another one wishes that the zombies could be made to obey one of them by making out with them. I think the others also make some wishes.

Later on, one of the students is playing at a football game and makes contact with an opponent, triggering a zombie outbreak. Another student's mother commits suicide by electrocuting herself in a bathtub via a toaster.

I think they figure out that, in order to stop the outbreak, they need to perform some kind of ritual or maybe gather some items. They end up succeeding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like ***[Dead Before Dawn 3D](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1989485/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (2012).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Before_Dawn):

> *Dead Before Dawn 3D* is a 2012 Canadian adventure-horror comedy directed by April Mullen, written by Tim Doiron, and starring Devon Bostick, Martha MacIsaac, and Christopher Lloyd. It introduces "zemons", a combination of zombie and demon. It is Canada's first stereoscopic live-action 3D feature film, and Mullen is the first woman to direct a live action, fully stereoscopic 3D feature film.
>
> Casper Galloway, an overcautious boy, has become afraid of anything dangerous since the day his father died in an accident at **the Occult Barn, his grandfather Horus's shop. When Horus receives a lifetime achievement award, Casper mans the shop so Horus can collect the trophy. Horus warns "no one is to come within spitting distance" of an urn kept on a high shelf topped with a skull. Horus goes on to explain that Casper's great grandfather Gilbert Galloway imprisoned a malevolent spirit inside the urn and it will curse the person that lets it out.**
>
> Charlotte, the girl Casper has a crush on, visits and he tries impressing her with a free purchase for loyal patronage to the Occult Barn. However, more of their friends arrive and make the situation worse. **Casper takes down the urn to show off to Charlotte and clumsily drops it. Casper tries warning them of the danger, but they laugh at him, thinking him to be paranoid. Skeptical, they invent a curse of their own: anyone with whom they make eye contact with after 10pm (since midnight is cliche) will kill themselves and come back as a "zemon", a zombie possessed by the evil demonic spirit entrapped in the urn. The zemons spread their infection through hickeys rather than bites, and those infected kill themselves and become zemons. As an additional rule, if someone gives a zemon a French kiss, the zemon will become their slave.** They are given until morning to undo the curse, or else they're cursed for eternity. However, they neglect to come up with an easier way to break the curse.

### Trailer